# Script to grab output lines after specific pattern

Tags: bash, shell

I have a program, "wimaxcu scan" to be precise, that outputs data in a format like the following:

```
network A
frequency
signal strength
noise ratio

network B
frequency
signal strength
noise ratio

etc....
```

There are a huge number of elements that get output by the program. I am only interested in a few of the properties of one particular network, say for example network J. I would like to write a bash script that will place the signal strength and noise ratio of J on a new line in a specified text file every time that I run the script. So after running the script many times I would have a file that looks like:

```
Point 1 signal_strength noise_ratio
Point 2 signal_strength noise_ratio
Point 3 signal_strength noise_ratio
etc...
```

I was advised to pipe the output into grep to accomplish this. I'm fairly certain that grep is not the best method to accomplish this because the lines I want to grab are indistinguishable from other noise and signal strengths lines. I'm thinking that the "network J" pattern would have to be recognized (it is unique), and then the lines that come 2nd and 3rd after the found pattern would be grabbed.

My question is how others would recommend that I implement such a script. I'm not very experienced with bash, so the simplest method would be appreciated, rather than a complex but efficient method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With awk!

If your data is in a file called "data," you can do this on the command line:

```
$ awk -v RS='\n\n' -v FS='\n' '{ print $1,$3,$4 }' data
```

What that will do is set your "record separator" to two newlines, the "field separator" to a single newline, and then print fields one, three, and four from each data set.

Awk, if you're not familiar, operates on records, and can do various things with them. So this simply says "a record looks like this, and print it this way." Specifically, "A record has fields that are separated by newlines, and each record is separated by two consecutive newlines. Print the first, third, and fourth fields of these records out for each record."

**Edit:** As Jo So (who fully read and comprehended what you were asking for) points out, you can add an if statement to the inside of the curly braces to specify a specific network. Or, if it were unique, you could just throw in a pipe to grep at the end. But his solution is more correct, since it will only match against that first field!

```
$ awk -v RS='\n\n' -v FS='\n' '{ if ($1 == "Network J") print $1,$3,$4 }' data
```

Comment: No need for `if` conditional. You can do regex match - `awk 'BEGIN {RS="\\n\\n"; FS="\\n";} /network J/{print $1,$3,$4}' data >> data1`

Comment: Thank you for the excellent answer, this was exactly what I was looking for

Comment: Jaypal - your regex match doesn't explicitly state that "network J" must be the first line. It could be any line, or could even span multiple lines (if the regex held the field separator, as in "work A\nfrequency").

Answer (score 2):

To complete Dan Fego's very good answer (sorry, it seems I'm not yet allowed to place comments), consider this:

```
awk -v RS='\n\n' -v FS='\n' '{if ($1 == "network J") print $3}' data
```

This is actually a very robust piece of code.

Answer (score 1):

Actually Grep is the right option.

What you have to do is use the -A (after) and -B (before) options of grep.  You can use something like:

```
grep "network J" -A 3   original_output
```

this will output the 3 lines after network J including the line network J.  But you don't want the words "network J" so

```
grep "network J" -A 3   original_output | grep -v "network J"
```

you  then have to put them in one line which is easily done by echoing the output as in:.

```
echo $(grep "network J" -A  original_output | grep -v "network J")
```

Now you will end up with all instances of Network J in the file. you can append them to an output

### Part A

```
   echo $(grep "network J" -A original_output | grep -v "network J") >> net_j_report.txt
```

adding Point 1 ... etc to the beginning can be done later by:

### Part B

```
   grep -v '^[[:space:]]*$' net_j_report.txt | cat -n | sed -e 's/^/Point /'
```

here grep -v removes any accidental empty lines, cat -n adds line numbers and last sed statement puts the word Point in the beginning.

so combine part A and B and voila.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you:

```
# cat file1 # same format for file2, file3, ...
network A
frequency
signalA strength
noise1 ratio

network B
frequency
signalB strength
noise1 ratio
# sed -n '/network/{s/network \(.\)/cat <<\\EOF >>\1/p;n;n;N;y/ /_/;s/\n/ /;s/$/\nEOF/p}' file1 | sh
# sed -n '/network/{s/network \(.\)/cat <<\\EOF >>\1/p;n;n;N;y/ /_/;s/\n/ /;s/$/\nEOF/p}' file2 | sh
# sed -n '/network/{s/network \(.\)/cat <<\\EOF >>\1/p;n;n;N;y/ /_/;s/\n/ /;s/$/\nEOF/p}' file3 | sh
# sed -i = A 
# sed -i 'N;s/^/Point /;s/\n/ /' A
# sed -i = B 
# sed -i 'N;s/^/Point /;s/\n/ /' B
# cat A     
Point 1 signalA_strength noise1_ratio
Point 2 signalA_strength noise2_ratio
Point 3 signalA_strength noise3_ratio
# cat B
Point 1 signalB_strength noise1_ratio
Point 2 signalB_strength noise2_ratio
Point 3 signalB_strength noise3_ratio
```